# How do I refer to the last commit in a branch with git?

Tags: git

Is there a way to refer to the last commit in a specific branch with git? Or the last N, for that matter?

Specifically, I would like to cherry-pick the last commit from a branch without having to get it's id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the name of the branch, it refers to the last commit in that branch.  For example, if your branch is called `feature`, then

```
git cherry-pick feature
```

picks the last commit, and

```
git cherry-pick feature~3..feature
```

picks the three last commits.

Answer (score 2):

The `N`th commit from last is `HEAD~$N`, with `HEAD` alone being the same as `HEAD~0`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the branchs' SHA1, you can use its name directly, example:

`git cherry-pick mybranch` cherry picks the latest SHA1 from that branch.

To cherrypick a few commits before mybranch's latest commit, you can use:

`git cherry-pick mybranch~3` for example cherry-picks the 3rd newest commit in mybranch.